# iFrame not showing inline HTML content

Tags: html, iframe

I have an iFrame on my site, and instead of using an `src` attribute, I want to show inline HTML within the iFrame. Is there any way I can do this?
Example:

```
<iframe><p>Hello World</p></iframe>
```

Should show text saying "Hello World" within an iFrame, but shows this instead:

```html
<iframe><p>Hello World</p></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`srcdoc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/srcdoc) attribute.

```html
<iframe srcdoc='<img src="https://i.ibb.co/7XxsBr5/lena02.png" alt="lena02" border="0" width="100">' height='150' width='150'></iframe>
```